# Trying to do an action skips straight to another action

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-game-engine

First of all, I know that I SHOULD be asking this at the Unity forums but I've asked twice and no one had the answer.

Now with that out of the way, this is a code I wrote for picking up and holding objects. My problem is that now whenever I try to pick up an object it goes straight to the drop action.
I think the problem starts at the if statement at line 42 in void Update.

Any help is appreciated.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

#pragma warning disable 0414

namespace CarryingItems {

public class PickUp : MonoBehaviour {

// publics

    public bool NearObject;

    // Where to place the item.
        private GameObject Hand;

    // The object I'm carrying.
        public static GameObject CarriedObject;

        public LayerMask RayMask;

// privates
    // The parent.
        private GameObject UtilityProps;

    private Rigidbody CORB;

    private bool ItemPickedUp; 

    private float OffsetDropPosition = 2;
    private RaycastHit FilterHit;

void Awake() {
    UtilityProps = GameObject.Find("UtilityProps");
    Hand = GameObject.Find("ItemHand");
}

void Update() {

    NearObject = PickUpSphereCasts.NearObject;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)){
        if (CarriedObject != null) {
                ItemDrop();
        }
        else if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.transform.position, Camera.main.transform.forward, out FilterHit, RayMask.value)){
            ItemPickUp(FilterHit.collider.gameObject);
            }
    }
}

 void ItemPickUp(GameObject objectToPickup) {
    // unless you've set your LayerMask to only hit the objects that can be picked up (you should do this as well, for optimization purposes), you must check if you can pick up this object
        if (objectToPickup.layer != 8) { // if you can't pick it up, do nothing then leave this function
            return;
        }

    if(NearObject == true){
        // from now on we know we are holding an item
            ItemPickedUp = true; 

        // make the scene modifications 
            CarriedObject = objectToPickup;

            CORB = CarriedObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

            CarriedObject.transform.SetParent(Hand.transform, false);

            CarriedObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
            CarriedObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;

            CarriedObject.transform.position = Hand.transform.position;
            CarriedObject.transform.rotation = Hand.transform.rotation;

            CarriedObject.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;
    }
}

 void ItemDrop() {
    // from now on, we do not have an object picked up
        ItemPickedUp = false;

    // make the scene modifications     
        CarriedObject.transform.SetParent(UtilityProps.transform, false);

        CarriedObject.transform.position = Camera.main.transform.position + Camera.main.transform.forward * OffsetDropPosition;
        CarriedObject.transform.rotation = Hand.transform.rotation;

        CarriedObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = true;
        CarriedObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;

        CarriedObject.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = true;

    // clear the reference             
        CarriedObject = null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: So, if you are pressing E and carried object is not null, you will drop it.. What do you want to accomplish? Hold the item while you are pressing E? That should make the rick:     if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)){
         if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.transform.position, Camera.main.transform.forward, out FilterHit, RayMask.value)){
            ItemPickUp(FilterHit.collider.gameObject);
         }
    } else if (CarriedObject != null) {
        ItemDrop();
    }

Comment: Easiest fix would be to just slap a `careAboutInput` bool in. Set it to false if the item is picked up or dropped and true if the getkeydown check is false. You can just check the bool with the getkeydown check.

Comment: @mayo I tried your fix and now the same thing happens but everything goes right for 1 frame.

Comment: My bad,, try with Input.GetKey instead of Input.GetKeyDown

Comment: @mayo Now I hold the object while I hold the key, but I want to press E to grab and hold it, and press E again to drop it.

Comment: Oh,, its weird. So, let start again. The first time that you press E close to a valid nearObject, you are able to pickup the item? Have you tried to use the debugger? Or some Logs to see what path your app is following?

Answer (score 0):

Create a private variable `careAboutInput` inside of the `PickUp` class, and use it to act as a switch in your `Update` function:

```
void Update() {

    NearObject = PickUpSphereCasts.NearObject;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)){
        if(careAboutInput){
            if (CarriedObject != null) {
                ItemDrop();
                careAboutInput = false;
            }
            else if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.transform.position, Camera.main.transform.forward, out FilterHit, RayMask.value)){
                ItemPickUp(FilterHit.collider.gameObject);
                careAboutInput = false;
            }   
        }
    }
    else {
        careAboutInput = true;
    }
}
```